# creating standalone executable iron python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I created a ironpython project in visual studio and I want it to run as executable

I tried creating the executable with pyc but it doesn't work(It does absolutly nothing).

`ipy.exe Tools\Scripts\pyc.py /main:"C:\<Path>\WpfApplication1.py" /target:winexe`

then i created a small sample project to see if that works

WpfApplication1.py

```
    import wpf
    from System.Windows import Application, Window


    class MyWindow(Window):
         def __init__(self):
            wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication1.xaml')
            self.button.Content = 'My Button'
            self.textbox.Text = 'My Text'

        def Button_Click(self, sender, e):
            self.label.Content = self.textbox.Text


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

and the xaml

```
    <Window 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="300"> 
   <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" />
</Grid>
```

same problem nothing happens when i execute it, how do I even debug that?

Comment: Did you remove your old question/thread without giving any credit? o0

Comment: Secondly, shouldn't `/target:winexe` be `/target:exe` ?

Comment: I accepted it before deleting it to create this question, I thought that would count. I tried editing the old question but it seems I don't have enought reputation for that. I use /target:winexe because its a wpf, otherwise it opens the cmd.

Comment: Ah right you're probably creating a GUI not a console application.

Comment: If you do not see anything whilst running your application you can switch to use /target:exe instead of /target:winexe. Then when you run the application from a command prompt you can see the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import clr
    clr.AddReference('IronPython.Wpf')
```

that did the trick